# Heroku, Node npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a very simple app that works fine locally, but I am having problems on heroku. I'm unable to get the app deployed.

My main file is index.js. Any idea why I'm getting the npm ERR! argv?

I'm also getting a timeout request near the bottom, but I'm pretty sure that's because of the error at the top, but I can't find any information on how to fix that.

My Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

Heroku Logs

```
2016-01-04T03:13:40.069853+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:974:3
2016-01-04T03:13:40.098240+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:13:40.116214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-01-04T03:13:40.116460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.1.1
2016-01-04T03:13:40.117293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
2016-01-04T03:13:40.117565+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-01-04T03:13:40.117685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 3-broadcast@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2016-01-04T03:13:40.117852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-01-04T03:13:40.118043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-01-04T03:13:40.118238+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 3-broadcast@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
2016-01-04T03:13:40.126696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-01-04T03:13:40.126957+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the 3-broadcast package,
2016-01-04T03:13:40.127149+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-01-04T03:13:40.127352+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-01-04T03:13:40.127528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node index.js
2016-01-04T03:13:40.127726+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-01-04T03:13:40.057500+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2016-01-04T03:13:40.127892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls 3-broadcast
2016-01-04T03:13:40.115774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
2016-01-04T03:13:40.128057+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-01-04T03:13:40.142232+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-01-04T03:13:40.142468+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-01-04T03:13:40.131714+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:13:41.074138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-04T03:13:58.421558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=e17561ec-a72c-4bda-a828-89d94b467eca fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-04T03:13:58.846066+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=f43b9355-785a-46c6-8b4b-d8242850eefa fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-04T03:13:41.079689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-04T03:13:34.108622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-04T03:16:03.635321+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b368561 by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:16:03.635321+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:16:03.859376+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T03:16:03.859386+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T03:16:05.130278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-01-04T03:16:07.541724+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:16:07.541734+00:00 app[web.1]: > 3-broadcast@1.0.0 start /app
2016-01-04T03:16:07.541735+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-01-04T03:16:07.541736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:16:08.850108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-04T03:17:00.281412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=51a122b3-29cf-4990-bdd3-87876aff7eb9 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:17:34.578076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=ea1ec7e0-9d21-4b75-a178-b1459c7f7b26 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30008ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:19:02.419204+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 455f4b9 by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:19:02.419204+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:19:02.554096+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T03:19:02.554106+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T03:19:02.521646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-01-04T03:19:03.765155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-01-04T03:19:06.461660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-04T03:19:06.859284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:19:06.859295+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-01-04T03:19:06.859293+00:00 app[web.1]: > 3-broadcast@1.0.0 start /app
2016-01-04T03:19:06.859295+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:19:07.496859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-04T03:19:07.678179+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2016-01-04T03:19:08.417595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2016-01-04T03:19:41.947257+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=9c09f36a-907f-46f8-987a-6643c4a8c812 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30013ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:20:12.792172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=13122c47-3da7-4225-8ecb-456e02300e98 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:30:30.747148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=173c5f06-e37f-4d58-851d-09a657bc6471 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:31:01.607943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=5a9b793c-33b7-4cbc-ba79-7d3fd03d6c9d fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:35:45.503236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=0619c426-5b9f-4466-9149-23a25c9f2c9f fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:36:16.605008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=7041b988-7754-4daf-b2cc-aa59d47af6a9 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T03:51:14.197715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-04T03:51:09.664826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-01-04T03:51:09.665575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-04T03:59:35.268346+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 76810f5 by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:59:35.268417+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T03:59:35.419230+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T03:59:35.419242+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T03:59:43.936272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-01-04T03:59:43.936548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-01-04T03:59:45.379956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-01-04T03:59:48.386628+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T03:59:48.386638+00:00 app[web.1]: > 3-broadcast@1.0.0 start /app
2016-01-04T03:59:48.386639+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2016-01-04T03:59:48.386640+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-04T04:00:21.016181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=adb01525-d9ab-4218-aeb9-d83663fa5c44 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T04:00:52.022088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=644b6a2e-7f10-45ca-96d4-160ed0c57511 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T04:12:47.063010+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T04:12:47.063020+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T04:12:46.926357+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ac9051e by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:12:46.926395+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:12:48.336084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-01-04T04:12:52.744593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-04T04:12:54.916240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-01-04T04:13:38.172796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=e2a82fa4-2cde-41c8-9ced-f07b364bc5cf fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T04:14:09.018120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blueredcircles.herokuapp.com request_id=42ff0959-f6b2-40a7-bd91-e133440a7219 fwd="67.202.159.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30007ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-04T04:22:13.685866+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy cd095d8 by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:22:13.685900+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:22:13.818747+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T04:22:13.818760+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T04:22:13.808044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-01-04T04:22:14.560498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-01-04T04:22:15.616097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-04T04:22:18.806289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-04T04:22:21.385366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-01-04T04:27:40.534025+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:27:40.533989+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 992d387 by john.steven.curry@gmail.com
2016-01-04T04:27:40.664281+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-04T04:27:40.664290+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-04T04:27:41.813131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-04T04:27:41.873956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-01-04T04:27:42.582874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

index.js:

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var alert = 'test hello from server :) ' + Math.random();
  socket.on('change color', function(){
    socket.broadcast.emit('change color');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('1 client disconnected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"engines": {
"node": "9.4.0",
"npm": "5.6.0" 
}
```

Add these in your package.json file.

EDIT:

Your Heroku npm version should be compatible with your node version running on the device.